# Meaning of "bei" in "Punkte bei jemandem sammeln"

Tags: preposition, meaning-in-context

> Mit seiner provokanten PR-Aktion zur Eröffnung wollte er Punkte ***bei*** linken Aktivisten sammeln.

What is the meaning of the preposition **bei** in the sentence above?

Answer (score 4):

It's based on the idea/metaphor of bookkeeping.
X gives Y points for good behavior.
And vice versa, Y tries to increase the number of points in X's book by behaving in a way X approves of.

So, in your example

> linke Aktivisten

are X

> er

is Y

Answer (score 4):

The *bei* in your example is not an exception, but the rule for a loose relation to a person:

- bei jemandem beliebt sein
- bei jemandem Schulden haben
- bei jemandem in der Kreide stehen
- Du hast einen Gefallen bei mir gut.

A closer relation to that person would more likely be phrased directly i.e. without preposition:

- jemanden lieben/hassen/verachten

Comment: Good examples! Interestingly, German indicates this relation via a locative preposition, whereas English does so by a comitative one ("with").

Answer (score 2):

The expression you're looking for is

> **bei** jemandem Punkte sammeln `or` Punkte **bei** jemandem sammeln

which is similar to

> **bei** jemandem punkten

This is translated as

> to score points **with** someone

So he tried to get on the good side of left activists.

Comment: I'm curious why somebody disagrees with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer to the question "Wo?" is a person or a group than you use "bei".[1]
Simply learn this as a rule.

e.g. Ich sitze bei meinem Vater. Peter ist bei seinen Eltern. Wir befinden uns bei der Oma.

to be at/with somebody
or, as in the question, to gain something at (in English it would be "from") somebody.

Not the most scientifical explanation, but it will do for practical purposes.

---

[1] This means: static Verb + persons ---> bei. (Dynamic, moving Verbs need "zu" for persons and answer the question "Wohin?")
Exception: Ich bin zuhause. Ich gehe nach Hause.